# How to know the outgoing call has answered or not?

Tags: android

I want to know the outgoing call is answered or not in android program.I just want to know the outgoing call has answered or not.I am new in android.Please help me to solve this problem.For getting the call answered time i use this.

I want to know the outgoing call is answered or not in android program. I just want to know the outgoing call has answered or not. I am new in android. Please help me to solve this problem. For getting the call answered time I use this.

```
    BroadcastReceiver mReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        if (intent.getAction().equals("android.intent.action.NEW_OUTGOING_CALL")) {
             savedNumber = intent.getExtras().getString("android.intent.extra.PHONE_NUMBER");


        } else {
            String stateStr = intent.getExtras().getString(TelephonyManager.EXTRA_STATE);
            String number = intent.getExtras().getString(TelephonyManager.EXTRA_INCOMING_NUMBER);
            int state = 0;
            if (stateStr.equals(TelephonyManager.EXTRA_STATE_IDLE)) {
                state = TelephonyManager.CALL_STATE_IDLE;
            } else if (stateStr.equals(TelephonyManager.EXTRA_STATE_OFFHOOK)) {
                state = TelephonyManager.CALL_STATE_OFFHOOK;
            } else if (stateStr.equals(TelephonyManager.EXTRA_STATE_RINGING)) {
                state = TelephonyManager.CALL_STATE_RINGING;
            }

            onCallStateChanged(context, state, number);
        }
    }
};


protected void onIncomingCallStarted(Context ctx, String number, Date start) {
}

protected void onOutgoingCallStarted(Context ctx, String number, Date start) {


}

protected void onIncomingCallEnded(Context ctx, String number, Date start, Date end) {
}

protected void onOutgoingCallEnded(Context ctx, String number, Date start, Date end) {

    SimpleDateFormat localDateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm:ss");
    startime = localDateFormat.format(start);
    endtime = localDateFormat.format(end);

    long aa = start.getTime();
    long bb = end.getTime();
    long cc = bb - aa;
    long diffMinutes = cc / 1000 % 60;
    duration = Long.toString(diffMinutes);

    Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
    bundle.putString("start", startime);
    bundle.putString("end", endtime);
    bundle.putString("duration", duration);

    Call_End dFragment = new Call_End();
    dFragment.setArguments(bundle);
    dFragment.show(fragmentManager, "Dialog Fragment");

}

protected void onMissedCall(Context ctx, String number, Date start) {
}

public void onCallStateChanged(Context context, int state, String number) {
    if (lastState == state) {
        //No change, debounce extras
        return;
    }
    switch (state) {


        case TelephonyManager.CALL_STATE_RINGING:
            isIncoming = true;
            callStartTime = new Date();
            savedNumber = number;
            onIncomingCallStarted(context, number, callStartTime);
            break;
        case TelephonyManager.CALL_STATE_OFFHOOK:

            callStartTime = new Date();
              onOutgoingCallStarted(context, savedNumber, callStartTime);

            //Transition of ringing->offhook are pickups of incoming calls.  Nothing done on them
            if (lastState != TelephonyManager.CALL_STATE_RINGING) {
                isIncoming = false;
                callStartTime = new Date();
                onOutgoingCallStarted(context, savedNumber, callStartTime);
    }
            break;
        case TelephonyManager.CALL_STATE_IDLE:
            //Went to idle-  this is the end of a call.  What type depends on previous state(s)
            if (lastState == TelephonyManager.CALL_STATE_RINGING) {
                //Ring but no pickup-  a miss
                onMissedCall(context, savedNumber, callStartTime);
            } else if (isIncoming) {
                onIncomingCallEnded(context, savedNumber, callStartTime, new Date());
            } else {
                onOutgoingCallEnded(context, savedNumber, callStartTime, new Date());
            }
            break;
    }
    lastState = state;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
    Log.d("Intent", intent.toString());
    if(intent.getAction().equals("android.intent.action.NEW_OUTGOING_CALL")) 
    {
        Log.e("Call_state","outgoing call detected");
    }

//        Checking for the call status
    try {
        // TELEPHONY MANAGER class object to register one listner
        TelephonyManager tmgr = (TelephonyManager) context.getSystemService(Context.TELEPHONY_SERVICE);
        //Create Listner
        MyPhoneStateListener PhoneListener = new MyPhoneStateListener();
        // Register listener for LISTEN_CALL_STATE
        tmgr.listen(PhoneListener, PhoneStateListener.LISTEN_CALL_STATE);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

private class MyPhoneStateListener extends PhoneStateListener {
    public void onCallStateChanged(int state, String incomingNumber) {
        switch (state) {
            case TelephonyManager.CALL_STATE_RINGING:
                Log.e("Call_state","call ringing");
                break;
            case TelephonyManager.CALL_STATE_OFFHOOK:
                Log.e("Call_state","call offhook");
                break;
            case TelephonyManager.CALL_STATE_IDLE:
                Log.e("Call_state","call idle");
                break;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do like this but this will not work on all phone.

1. Create notification listener service which tell you another person has pick up the call.`public class CallNotification extends NotificationListenerService {
   public void onNotificationPosted(StatusBarNotification sbn)
   {
   //your code here after you getting notification another person has pick up the call
   }
   }`
2. Ask for the allow notification from the system.

   `Intent intent = new Intent("android.settings.ACTION_NOTIFICATION_LISTENER_SETTINGS");
   startActivity(intent);`